# HTTP request path is empty in working with Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

So I jut created a controller like this:

```
require 'net/http'
class HowdyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    url = URI.parse("http://google.com")
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
    @resp = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req)}
  end
end
```

and my route is like this:

```
get "howdy/show"
```

and my view is lie this:

```
<h1>Howdy#show</h1>
<%= "The call to example.com returned this: #{@resp}" %>
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/howdy/show` I get this error

> HTTP request path is empty

I am totally new to Net::HTTP and just trying to create something simple that works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_response` and pass the URL as the first argument, and a slash as the second one to make the path:

```
@resp = Net::HTTP.get_response("www.google.com", "/")
```

Answer (score 4):

To send a request using `net/http` do:

```
        uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
        #This makes the request
        resp = http.request(request)
```